# Задержка удаления файла

Tags: c#, файлы, mp3

Такая ситуация:
Работает программа, пользователь удаляет `mp3` файл, нужно узнать `ID3` данные файла или задержать удаления файла на секунды и опять таки узнать метаданные. С получением `ID3` данных проблем нет, но нужно оставить файл на время

Comment: Программа какая удаляет, ваша или сторонняя?

Comment: Вообще-то вы не сможете предотвратить удаление файла: пользователь может запустить процесс от имени администратора, а администратору можно всё. Расскажите, чего на самом деле вы хотите добиться.

Comment: Работает моя программа. Пользователь удаляет файл в папке. Мне нужно задержать удаление, получить от файла данные и продолжить удаления. Какой файл удаляется я знаю

Comment: А что мешает получить данные заранее? Перехватить удаление вы так просто не сможете, надо лезть на очень низкий уровень.

Answer (score 1):

Держите файл открытым для чтения и записи. Это максимально ограничивает возможность его удаления другим процессом.

Если вас не устраивает держать файл все время открытым, остается лишь вариант взламывать драйвер файловой системы, чтобы он создавал сообщение для вашей программы и ожидал окончания обработки перед удалением.

Другими методами вы не сможете узнать об удалении файла до того, как он будет удален. В пример можно привести FileSystemWatcher из .NET framework который сообщит вам об удалении файла уже после того, как файл удален. Поищите другой способ, пересмотрите концепцию вашего решения: может можно хранить отдельную базу данных с тегами?

Comment: 1. Слишком много файлов будет открыто для записи и чтения. 
2. Как мне узнать что пользователь хочет удалить файл